# ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl

Tags: tomcat

I published a JAX-WS styles webservice on tomcat 6. This webservice itself consumes a JAX-RPC style webservice. As soon as i include the call to the RPC webservice, i get the error below. The error is not present when i don't call the RPC style webservice.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl
at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.StubBase._postSendingHook(StubBase.java:231)
at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.StreamingSender._send(StreamingSender.java:324)
at DVSEWSPackage.DejonghewsRPC_Stub.DVSE_Webservice(DejonghewsRPC_Stub.java:459)
at DVSEWSPackage.DVSEWSClass.GetArticleInformation(DVSEWSClass.java:73)
at erpservice.webapp.dvse.ErpMessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(ErpMessageReceiverInOut.java:48)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:167)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:142)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4):

The axis2 saaj implementation is clashing with the saaj-ri implementation. You should clean up your classpath of unappropiate JAR's, look up for something like saaj-ri-....jar and axis2....jar

Comment: Thanks for this..it was actually conflicting with other jars in my class path. I was struggling with this for the past 2 days... :).... but your  answer fixed the problem :D...thanks a ton.